# Angular 8 error. ‘show’ does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular

I'am new to angular 8.
I'am currently doing a small assignment for college but with this all Covid 19 thing happening communication with the lecture is limited and because of this is slowing my down.

I googled the error for ages and cant seem to find whats wrong.

Thanks.

[image]

```
<button (click)="show = !show">{{show ? 'Hide' : 'Add a car'}}</button>

<div *ngIf="show">
    <form>
        <label>Make</label>
        <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Enter Make" #make>

        <label>Model</label>
        <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Enter Model" #model>

        <label>Year</label>
        <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Enter Year" #year>

        <button type="submit" (click)="addTheCar(make.value,
             model.value,year.value)">Add the Car</button>
    </form>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <app-car *ngFor="let carData of carsData" [carData]="carData"></app-car>
</div>
```

This is the carlist.component.html(where the error sends me)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ICar, Car } from '../interfaces/car';
import { CarApiService } from '../services/car-api.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-carlist',
  templateUrl: './carlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carlist.component.css'],
  providers: [CarApiService]
})
export class CarlistComponent implements OnInit {
  carsData: ICar[];

  constructor(private _carAPIService:CarApiService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void{
    this._carAPIService.getCarData().subscribe(carsData =>
      {this.carsData = carsData});
  }

  addTheCar(make:string, model:string, year:string):boolean{
    let tempCar:ICar;
    tempCar= new Car(make,model,year);
    this._carAPIService.addCarData(tempCar);
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define `show` in `CarlistComponent.ts`

```
export class CarlistComponent implements OnInit {
    show:boolean;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is what it says: there is no `show` property on your component. Add `show = false;` under your `carsData` line and it should go away.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ICar, Car } from '../interfaces/car';
import { CarApiService } from '../services/car-api.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-carlist',
  templateUrl: './carlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carlist.component.css'],
  providers: [CarApiService]
})
export class CarlistComponent implements OnInit {
  carsData: ICar[];
  show:boolean;

  constructor(private _carAPIService:CarApiService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void{
    this._carAPIService.getCarData().subscribe(carsData =>
      {this.carsData = carsData});
  }

  addTheCar(make:string, model:string, year:string):boolean{
    let tempCar:ICar;
    tempCar= new Car(make,model,year);
    this._carAPIService.addCarData(tempCar);
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

specify a boolean value for show

```
export class CarlistComponent implements OnInit {
    public show = true;
```

Only when show = true this div will get executed

```
<div *ngIf="show">
    <form>
        <label>Make</label>
        <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Enter Make" #make>

        <label>Model</label>
        <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Enter Model" #model>

        <label>Year</label>
        <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Enter Year" #year>

        <button type="submit" (click)="addTheCar(make.value,
             model.value,year.value)">Add the Car</button>
    </form>

</div>
```